# junit-4.8.2.jar; zip END header not found

Tags: java, maven

I tried following [this](https://github.com/CaptainObvious0/NoCheatPlus/wiki/Compiling-NoCheatPlus) guide and ran into a compile error which seems to be related to Maven. Error log is available here pastebin.com/6XUhzbPv. I'd appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: The simplest part solution is to delete the files in $HOME/.m2/repository/junit/ but there is another issue turn on checksums ... see about more details here: https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Comment: Thank you for linking that. I did try deleting .m2/repository/junit earlier with no luck as well as trying an older version of Maven (Just to try). I assume that some repository is no longer available.